# How to make a page view controller work with 3 table views?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have 3 arrays of data I want to display in 3 different tables. I want to show one set of data (on the table) at a time while being able to swipe left or right to see the other data.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Right now, the page controller isn't hooked up to anything but the tableView works fine. I also would like to have the same Cell for every table.

Basically, I just need the data to change when you swipe on the table. How can I do this?

It seems I need to add a scroll view under the tableView but I am not 100% sure. I can't seem to find any tutorials on just adding a page view controller.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at UIPageViewController?  You could use this with three instances of your tableview controller

Comment: ^^^^^ This is the right way to go.